# PyQt5 Combining QLabel Alignments

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am unable to combine two alignment flags as per Qt.Alignment documentation which reads: "You can use at most one horizontal and one vertical flag at a time. counts as both horizontal and vertical." <https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/Qt.html%5C>

This this code snippet should work for a QLabel being added to QGridLayout to align the text vertically in the center of the label, and on the right edge.

```
        field_label = QLabel(fld_player[e] + ':  ')
        field_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        field_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.data_layout.addWidget(field_label, grid_row, grid_col)
```

However, the last 'setAlignment' statement becomes the dominant one.  ***At issue is how to make both active***.

Thinking order of statement significant, changing the order of execution results in the last 'setAlignment' statement becoming the dominant one.

Reasoning the two alignment flags were single bits in a word (right = 2, vcenter = 128, added = 130 of \b10000010) I have tried adding ('+') the two flags producing a type(int) and a TypeError; 'and'ing is tried with the first in the pair being dominant (not the commutative law).

I am out of ideas.

Comment: Read about [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and how they usually [work in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) as in most other languages, [Python included](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Answer (score 0):

Use the bitwise OR operator `|`

I modified your example like this

```
field_label = QLabel(fld_player[e] + ':  ')
field_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
self.data_layout.addWidget(field_label, grid_row, grid_col)
```

Comment: Beautiful, I did not expect an 'or'.  Thank you.